# What is the eponym associated with the relationship between phase variance and expected magnitude?

Tags: turbulence, coherence

I'm looking for the eponym (e.g., [Stigler's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy)) associated with the following relationship:

\begin{equation}
\left|\langle e^{-i\phi} \rangle\right| = e^{-\langle\phi^2\rangle/2}
\end{equation}

which is related to signal fading, scintillation, turbulence, speckle, and a variety of other interesting fields and phenomena.  I have located it in print (behind a paywall) in [Yeh and Liu (1982)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1456581), equation (3.11), but they do not supply a name.  My own memory fails me, and I am finding it difficult to phrase a search for an equation. Does anyone recognize a name (or names) associated with this relationship/property?